# How to use Kafka Connect to deliver Protobuf messages to Elasticsearch?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am using this confluent protobuf example:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Protobuf   to produce messages of type “Term” according to this Protobuf file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package confluent.kafka.examples.protobuf;
message Section {
  string Id = 1;
  string SectionName = 2;
}
message Term {
  string TermId = 1;
  string TermName = 2;
  repeated Section Section = 3;
}
```

These messages need to find their way to Elasticsearch, so I am adding this ES connector:

```
PUT  localhost:8083/connectors/protobuftopic/config
    {
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
      "type.name": "_doc",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "topics": "protobuftopic",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
      "name": "protobuftopic”,
      "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
      "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
      "key.ignore": "true",
      "schema.ignore": "true"
    }
```

Now we have a running connector:

```
localhost:8083/connectors/protobuftopic/status
{
  "name": "protobuftopic",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083"
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

I then produce a few messages and print them using KSQL:

```
ksql> print protobuftopic from beginning;
Key format: KAFKA_INT or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: PROTOBUF or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/07/08 19:05:08.436 Z, key: 1952805485, value: TermId: "123" TermName: "Term-123" Section { Id: "0" SectionName: "Section-123" }, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/07/08 19:05:08.914 Z, key: 1952805485, value: TermId: "123" TermName: "Term-123" Section { Id: "1" SectionName: "Section-123" }, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/07/08 19:05:08.923 Z, key: 1952805485, value: TermId: "123" TermName: "Term-123" Section { Id: "2" SectionName: "Section-123" }, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/07/08 19:05:08.932 Z, key: 1952805485, value: TermId: "123" TermName: "Term-123" Section { Id: "3" SectionName: "Section-123" }, partition: 0
rowtime: 2021/07/08 19:05:08.942 Z, key: 1952805485, value: TermId: "123" TermName: "Term-123" Section { Id: "4" SectionName: "Section-123" }, partition: 0
```

When I examine the state of my ES connector, I see the following:

```
    {
      "name": "protobuftopic",
      "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083"
      },
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "state": "FAILED",
          "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083",
          "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:498)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:478)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)\n\t
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic protobuftopic to Protobuf: \n\tat io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter.toConnectData(ProtobufConverter.java:131)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertKey(WorkerSinkTask.java:535)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:498)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Protobuf message for id -1\n


Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!\n"
        }
      ],
      "type": "sink"
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the reason for the "unknown magic byte" error was the absence of explicit "key converter" definition. The connector assumed Protobuf and was failing. This issue was solved by specifying

```
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

so the overall connector config looks like this:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "protobuftopic",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "name": "protobuftopic",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable":true,
    "errors.log.include.messages":true
   
}
```